# How to capture error details within a while loop?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that checks if the connection to an Ip address is live. I have added a timer to the code so it loops and checks for 4 minutes then sleeps then starts again. I have also added this script to Task Scheduler that runs every 5 minutes.

However, my problem is the script only capture the error details if the errors occurs outside the while loop. If there is an error while the code is looping, the error variable is empty and unfortunately all the errors occur within the loop.

This is the code I have. Apart from the above, everything works fine. Any suggestions or answers?

```
function Make_Decision() {
    if ($val -eq 0) {
        $msg = "Connection to [$IPaddress] FAILED`n"
        Add-Content -path C:\path\results.txt -value "[$date] - { $msg }"
        Send_Email_Groups
    }
}

function Test_Port_Connection() {
    $date = Get-Date -Format g
    $portNumber = 0000
    $IPaddress = '000.00.00.00'
    $timeout = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 4
    $sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
    $host_connection = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient
    try {
        $host_connection.Connect($IPaddress, $portNumber)
    } catch {
        $erro = "[$date] - $_"
        $erro | Out-File C:\path\errors.txt -Append
    }
    while ($sw.elapsed -lt $timeout) {
        if (($host_connection.Connected) -and (Test-Connection -IPAddress $IPaddress -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
            $val = 1
        } else {
            $val = 0
            break
        }
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    } # end of while loop
    Make_Decision
}

Test_Port_Connection
```

Comment: So, run the `while` loop inside the `try` or add another `try..catch` in the body of the loop.

Comment: Could you give more information about the "error" you are trying to address? You said "If there is an error while the code is looping, the error variable is empty and unfortunately all the errors occur within the loop." So how do you know there is an error at all?

Comment: @jazzdelightsme ...any connection error that might occur when pinging the IP address defined. I didnt use the correct IP address for security purposes

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I just edited the code to try your suggestion. Its now loaded into task scheduler and I am waiting to see if I will get the desired results whenever the connection fails.

Answer (score 1):

The reason there is no $error variable is because powershell is evaluating `$host_connection.Connected` first which is false, so the second statement `Test-Connection -IPAddress $IPaddress -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` never gets run and therefore the output never gets assigned to the $error variable

If you switch them round then the test will be run and you can receive the error variable from within your while loop:

Instead of

```
if (($host_connection.Connected) -and (Test-Connection -IPAddress $IPaddress -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
```

you will have

```
if ((Test-Connection -IPAddress $IPaddress -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -and ($host_connection.Connected))
```

Comment: Okay. so that slight change will cause the code to capture an error? or I will have to  make some other variable change somewhere else in the code? This is my first time using powershell. For example how would I now get that error details to append to an error log file?

Comment: you could use something like this in your if statement:
`$erro = "[$date] - $error"`
`$erro | Out-File C:\path\errors.txt -Append`

Comment: Okay thanks, that snippet of code would go in the IF or the ELSE? I am a little confused. Basically what I'm trying to do is if an error is detected while executing the while loop, then I want to record the error then break out the loop and jump to the Make_Decision function as stated in the main question. How would you go about doing that

Comment: In the IF statement, and that's two lines. I can only take you so far and you'll have to experiment with what you get/want from here.